# How does one run a program from an HTA?

Tags: javascript, hta, activexobject

What activeXobject to use for running a .exe program from an HTA, pipe data into it, and receive the output?

Can you even call DLLs somehow?

Comment: You can run commandline commands via WScript.Shell and its Run method.

Comment: @Teemu WScript? Is that available in an HTA? That's WSH, isn't it?

Comment: It is available: `var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`

Comment: @Teemu Great! Thanks, I'll try that.